# trying to determine if my threadpool as a memory leak using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor. I create a new CRIRunnerThreads and submit them
over and over again to the CRIThreadPool after the last one completes.
My concern is , that if you look at the second snippet of code i have the logger display ThreadAllocatedBytes after the process is complete. At the beginning of the process i see output like:

```
2013-06-27 [pool-1-thread-1] ThreadAllocatedBytes:416.7 MB  (INFO)
```

At the end of the run i see

```
2013-06-28 [pool-1-thread-1] ThreadAllocatedBytes:4.5 GB  (INFO)
```

by the time it reaches 4GB i have probably submitted and completed 400 CRIRunnerThread's

I am assuming (and this is what i am asking here) , that the threads in the ThreadPoolExecutor are getting larger and larger and never recycling/CG;g?

Is this a correct assumption and is there something i am suppose to do once the thread/worker is finished?

Or am i using the ThreadMXBean incorrectly?

```
public CRIThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, 
       long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
       BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
         super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
         FutureObjs = Collections.synchronizedMap( new HashMap<Future, Thread>() );
}
```

my corePoolSize is 2 and maximumPoolSize is 4 (this is a small devel box)

in my thread i have

```
public class CRIRunnerThread extends Thread {
     public void run() {
        //instantiates a class and call a long running process
        //when complete display the threadAllocatedBytes

        com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean tBean = 
             (com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean) ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

        long bytes = tBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        logger.info(("(" + mrn + ")ThreadAllocatedBytes:" +  
                        FormUtils.humanReadableByteCount(bytes, true)));
     }

}
```

Comment: Why are you submitting *threads* to the pool at all? The point of a thread pool is to reduce the number of threads used. You should just implement Runnable rather than extending Thread. (If you don't call `start` then it probably won't be allocating a "real" thread, but it's still an odd thing to do.)

Comment: the main reason i was using threads was i needed to change the name for what i was doing. Using using threads instead of implementing Runnable causing the problem i am seeing?

Comment: I don't know, but I strongly suspect the name isn't actually doing what you think it's doing. If the work for one `Thread` object is being *executed* on a different one, you'll be getting very confusing diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am going to do a little re factoring to a Runnable

Comment: re-factored CRIRunnerThread to implement Runnable.
i am not sure if getThreadAllocatedBytes is giving me correct info or not. I can see it increase each time a new thread runs, but when i a top i do not see any really large memory processes. The latest one today says "2013-07-01 07:17:21 [pool-1-thread-1] [CRIRunner] (1976699)ThreadAllocatedBytes:14.1 GB  (INFO)
"